# Handle multiple PHP script calls from multiple XHR instances

Tags: php, jquery, apache, validation, jquery-file-upload

*Previously styled question: http://pastebin.com/cr432nLQ*

I've decided to rephrase the whole question about this problem and go as thoroughly as possible. You can read the previously asked question in the paste above.

First of all, thanks to everyone for their responses, but unfortunately, they got me nowhere. I'm still in need of help for my problem.

So, I'm using a jQuery plugin named **blueimp jQuery File Upload** which takes care of asynchronous file uploading very nicely and it includes a lot of options. The plugin works good enough for my purposes, but there is this server side check I need to perform in order to save myself from abusive users. **I'm talking about limiting the number of uploads *that occur at once***.

The plugin works as follows by default: User selects a number of files (or drops them to the drop zone) and each file creates a separate XHR instance which then calls my `upload.php` script, which takes care of storing the files. The PHP upload script handles the XHR requests as if it was only one image, so basically, each image that requires uploading, calls the `upload.php` script separately.

What I'm allowing to upload my users is images. However, I want to apply some limits to the upload count to **10** for free users and **20** for premium users. This is possible to be done via Javascript, yes, but I don't really trust Javascript for this kind of validation, hence I'm seeking a server side validation. But, how? This is quite of impossible (for me at least) to be done securely. I need to somehow make sure on my upload script that the user did not exceed the **10** (or 20) image uploads limit.

I found out that this jQuery plugin has this option named `singleFileUploads`:

> By default, each file of a selection is uploaded using an individual
>   request for XHR type uploads. Set this option to false to upload file
>   selections in one request each.
>
> Note: Uploading multiple files with one request requires the multipart
>   option to be set to true (the default).
>
> - Type: boolean
> - Default: `true`

This quite does what I need it to do - Sends an entirely filled `$_FILES` array with all the submitted image uploads. But I still see a problem with this. This is still being decided by Javascript itself. Can an user modify this part of the script and set `singleFileUploads` to `false` again? I think they can! If they couldn't, then this question is answered right now - but I don't know.

There is an answer below that suggests the use of Apache's `mod_qos` to limit the image uploads quantity, but I don't have a clue how to make it differ for the two different user types (free and premium).

*Please be aware that guests are allowed to upload image as well and the free user limit should apply to them.*

---

**So what have I tried regarding all this?**

I have tried creating a solution with sessions that would keep track on how much the user is uploading and for each new upload, the session's value would increment for one - A solution that was not secure enough as suggested below, since the cookies can be cleared. Beside this try, I wasn't able to apply anything from the answers below.

---

**The question**

Well, the question is quite clear since the beginning: How do I limit the number of concurrent image uploads to **10** for guests/free users and **20** to premium users *securely*?

**EDIT:** I guess it's worth mentioning that each uploaded image gets its own row in the database, with the time of the upload and name. Maybe this could help!

Thank you.

Comment: Use `session`s and/or track by IP address.

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: A session won't help you since anyone can clear the session cookies and start fresh (so if a malicious user wanted to upload lots of images, he can easily write a script that will not even care about session cookies and it'll upload as much images as he wants).

Comment: @André Do you have any solution to suggest? I don't know how else to achieve this safely. This is quite irritating.

Comment: Do you want the user to select 10 images at once? Or just upload a maximum of 10 images disregarding when they upload the images?

Comment: I just want an user to be able to upload **maximally** 10 images for one *upload session*, like be able to select 10 images at once and have them upload at once. If the user was able to avoid the JS check if selecting more than 10, then PHP would take care of stopping that user. However, once the user has its upload finished, he can come 5 seconds later and do another 10 images upload. So I'm basically trying to limit an user uploading more than 10 images for one "upload session" (don't know how else to refer to it).

Comment: I still say use cookies but you need a mechanism to handle the current ip with session in cookies.

Comment: try upload progress module http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress so you can monitor upload by JS and PHP.

Answer (score 3):

From your comment, I understand your question as : "I want to limit the number of simultaneous upload connections per client (say: max 10 simultaneous uploads per client)"

*First off* : I haven't looked in details at your javascript plugin, but I think it already allows that. There should at least be an option to limit the number of simultaneous requests.
[edit] found it : [**limitconcurrentuploads**](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#limitconcurrentuploads) [/edit]

*More generally* : PHP is not the tool for the job. On the server side, the file upload (i.e: the process of receiving data through an http connexion and storing it in a file on the server's drive) is handled by apache (or nginx, or whatever) *before* the PHP script is called. When your PHP script starts, the file is already uploaded, you cannot interrupt the transfer from inside the script.

On the server side, you should look at your `php.ini / httpd.conf` options, or your `apache / .htaccess` setup. `php.ini` offers some options regarding [File uploads (doc)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads).

Your best go is to write this limitation in javascript, on the client side.

If you really want to bullet proof your *server*, you should study how you can configure your apache server to limit the number of simultaneous connections from a same IP to a given URL (I haven't found a quick, standard way to do that though).

---

For the last part : I found these questions on ServerFault

[Apache2: Limit simultaneous requests & throttle bandwidth per IP/client? (2011)](https://serverfault.com/questions/125168/apache2-limit-simultaneous-requests-throttle-bandwidth-per-ip-client)
[URL-based request rate limiting in Apache (2011)](https://serverfault.com/questions/338869/url-based-request-rate-limiting-in-apache)

The accepted answer to the first question points to the following apache module :
[mod_qos](http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/)

I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Yes php only starts after the upload to the webserver has completed -- then you can choose to throw it away / error but it won't prevent you from a denial of service type of attack.

Comment: I think I'm more interested in the Apache checks rather than the JS checks, since I've limited the upload quantity there already. From the  File Uploads (doc) I've understood that setting `max_file_uploads` to 10 should work. Can you demonstrate the last paragraph of yours? I'd really like to know how to limit simultaneous connection from the same IP to a given URL. This would still be related to this question...

Comment: That looks quite good to me. However since I need to separate the number of requests based on the users account type (10 guests and free accounts; 20 premium accounts) would I be able to go anywhere with mod_qos?

Answer (score 2):

You could create an activation code (i.e. a random number) when generating the host page (the page issuing the xhr calls) and pass it to the script as a variable inside the page. Then you can modify your js script to pass the activation code as a get parameter to the script handling the file upload. This way you can use the activation code as the key of a db table to store and track the number of uploads executed with that code.

Note that almost everything can be manipulated over HTTP/TCP (not just sessions) so you should just ask yourself what an attacker can achieve if he/she manages to exploit your protocol.

You didn't write much about the context of this question, but if your concern is the exploitation of resources you could ask your users to open an account with your service and set a hourly/daily/weekly maximum uploaded-GBs-allowance for each account.

Hope it helps.

PS. are you sure you really need to limit the number of uploads per upload-session? Since every upload is handled separately with a separate call to the upload script, if think it could be safe to allow the user to upload as many images he wishes.

Comment: Well, I found out that I can set `singleFileUploads` to true in my jQuery plugin to send all files in one XHR instance, but this could be modified. Making my website available to registered users only is great and I would like that, but the problem is that most of the traffic would come from unregistered users and I don't know if I'd manage to make them register. That'd cause loss of traffic. I have to limit the number of uploads because I also offer premium services and the benefits from a normal user have to differ from a premium user (eg. Free user gets 10 simultaneous uploads premium 20).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding your goal, but couldn't you just assign the session variable to another, reset the session variable before each loop, and make a comparison using the sum of the $_SESSION count and the "previous" count? Are you trying to prevent more than 10 aggregate uploads from each user, or just preventing 10 consecutive uploads in one go?

```
// Before starting your loop, assign your session variable to another.
$previously_uploaded = $_SESSION['images_session_uploaded'];

// Reset $_SESSION['images_session_uploaded'] at onset
$_SESSION['images_session_uploaded'] = 0;

// ... Do yo' thang.

// Make a comparison at the end of each loop for whatever you're checking against.
if (($_SESSION['images_session_uploaded'] + $previously_uploaded) >= MAX_FREEUSER_UPLOADS_SESSION)
{
  // User has uploaded more than ten images total, but not necessarily more than ten in this round of uploads. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off using **sessions** will protect you again the average user, but if someone knows what they are doing they could simply wipe their cookies and as far as your server can tell they are a **new user**.

Perhaps you could uniquely identify each user either by getting them to login or tracking their IP address or browser signature? It depends on your application.

The key issue here appears to be your use of the undefined phrase *upload session*. **What is an upload session?** Here I'm assuming it is a 30 minute period. So we are limiting them to 10 uploads every half an hour.

Solution using sessions:

```
// Start sessions before you can use them
session_start();

// "Config"
$_MAX_UPLOAD_COUNT = MAX_FREEUSER_UPLOADS_SESSION; // limit to this every session timeout
$_SESSION_TIMEOUT = 60 * 30; // 30 mins

// Current upload count (default to zero)
$total_uploads_so_far = isset($_SESSION['total_uploads']) ? $_SESSION['total_uploads'] : 0;

// --- Count their uploads this session ---
// #1 Either by looping through the uploads
$uploaded_image += 1;

// #2 Or before handling the upload by counting the amount of uploaded files
$uploaded_images = count($_FILES['images']);

// They've exhausted their uploads immediately
if($uploaded_images > $_MAX_UPLOAD_COUNT) {
  // Throw an error saying you can't select more than 10 images at once
  // Don't upload any images or modify the sessions.
}

// --- Before finishing the upload check that they haven't uploaded more than 10 items ---

// Have they uploaded before, was it in the past 30 mins?
$uploaded_recently = isset($_SESSION['last_upload']) && ($_SESSION['last_upload'] + $_SESSION_TIMEOUT) > time();

if($uploaded_recently && ($total_uploads_so_far + $uploaded_images) > $_MAX_UPLOAD_COUNT) {
  // Fail to upload, throw an error etc

} else {
  // Process your upload

  // Update the info in the users session
  $_SESSION['last_upload') = time();
  $_SESSION['total_uploads') = $uploaded_images + $total_uploads_so_far;

}
```

Solution using IP/signature:

Do the same as the above, however, instead of storing the last upload time and total upload count in the users `$_SESSION` store them in a **database** or a text file.

Set the **key** as their ip address (from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`), or something else to uniquely identify them. This will allow you to look it up per user (or pseudo user if using an IP address).

For example (using a file):

```
$uploads = unserialize(file_get_contents('uploads.txt');
if(!$uploads) $uploads = array();

// To update the user (using variables from the above example)
$uploads[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']] = array('total_uploads' => $uploaded_images + $total_uploads_so_far, 'last_upload' => time());

file_put_contents('uploads.txt', serialize($uploads));
```

Comment: I'm looking to avoid the session solution since it's not secure enough as you've stated. So I'm looking for a more secure solution. Since I'm allowing users to upload without **being registered**, I can't rely on this one either, so IPs it is. **Upload session** is just a name to refer to the ability to upload *10* images **at once**; this is what I'm referring to as an **upload session**. 30 minutes is too much to wait. If an user uploaded 10 images AT ONCE, he can immediately start another 10 after his first ten finished, but not 20 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would handle it would be to track uploads via IP address, which still is not 100% accurate.

Create a database table `uploads` like so:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  id (unsigned int, auto increment) |  ip (varchar) |  timestamp (current timestamp)|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

then run the following query to find how many the user has uploaded in the past half hour

```
SELECT * FROM `uploads` WHERE `ip` = '{$userIP}' AND `timestamp` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

count the rows using your chosen PHP database wrappers count method, and if the number is less than 10, allow the image save.

if the image is uploaded, run

```
INSERT INTO `uploads` (`ip`) VALUES ('{$userIP}')
```

Comment: Again, this is not what I am looking for. I do not want to limit an user to 10 images in 30 minutes. I just don't want an user to upload more than 10 images at once. He might upload 10 images right after the first 10 have finished uploading.

Comment: are all of the images being uploaded at the same time? Like in the same `$_FILES` array?

if so, count them `count($_FILES['images'])`.

If not, then the fact that you want to limit uploads based on separate XHR instances but on the same queue makes it a little more difficult, depending on the number of simultaneous requests and the amount of time required to upload each individual file.

What is the purpose of limiting the upload if it is the case that they're seperate XHR instances, if you then want to enable them to upload another 10 straight away?

Comment: Well, the reasons are pretty much obvious: I don't want to cause too much stress on the server and there are always restrictions to separate a free account from a premium account.

Answer (score 0):

So why not just keep a running count of all uploads by IP or IP / User-agent (still spoofable but better than cookies)

So before you start your upload your ajax makes a precheck call with the list of filenames.

the php code writes a record for each file to the db.

ip  /  user-agent / filename or unique fileid  / last-updated

You delete any old records last-updated older than a timeout 30 minutes or 2 days whatever old is. (This protects them if their upload gets killed by a network connection, ect

Then you count the number rows for that ip/user-agent and return an error via ajax.  This is all in a precheck before the actual upload.

In your upload code you check if the file has a row in the database.  If it doesn't they bypassed the precheck (or exceeded your timeout) and you don't save the file and instead issue an error.  If it does have a record you save the upload file and delete the record.

You have to pick a timeout carefully if the time to actually upload an image exceeds your timeout they will never be able to complete an upload.  If their upload gets killed quickly.  Ie their internet drops then they will not be able to get past the precheck until the timeout period expires.

As stated elsewhere php only runs after the upload has already completed with your webserver.  So at best you are just taking the benefit away of running multiple uploads in different tabs, etc.  You are not protecting yourself from a denail of service type of attack.  For that you need an apache rate limit extension or use iptable rules.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, where I wanted to limit total disk space each user uploads. (I had unique ID for user in database, you can use IP). Here are the things I did

1. When page was loaded, I created a hash of random string(salt + time) and saved it in session.
2. When file/files were uploaded, the same hash has to be sent via POST. if mismatch, the upload will be rejected. After successful file upload, random string would be changed. Hence new files can be uploaded from same form without reloading.
3. After upload, I'd maintain a ini file per user(per ip) which had records of number of files uploaded, file size uploaded. I'd reject the file if limits reached. I preferred file in this case as I did not need central database to analyse. Also there was no need to index/search/maintain relations to order database. In case you want to use database, I'd suggest separate sqlite database per user/ip for faster queries.

IP is more reliable one as User agent can be spoofed and cookies can be cleared(hence clearing session ID form browser). Even the IP can be reset if you have dynamic IP. If you are getting too many requests and you think you are under attack, you can temporarily disable uploads for all.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do what ever you want but when the upload is finished just send back the result with a verifying of the status of the user which requested the upload and exactly there you may clear the session if the user is/is not exist, they won't receive the result if they change their ip address or session key.

you may hold a simple key in db/session to delivery the result to the right user.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to prevent a user from uploading too many files per a time period. In order to do that you actually need to identify the user in the server side (assuming any client side mechanism can be manipulated) without a registration. I'm afraid that's not possible.

But, you have 2 pretty good choices:

1. Identify the user with client side, cookies, sessions, ip, user agent or any other factors and/or combination of them, thus, making a malicious user work hard to exploit your system holes. It's not perfect, but it will prevent most of the average users attempts.
2. Use a server side authentication system. You mentioned that you don't want to loose traffic, but let's thinks about it, if your free users don't even take a minute to register (only email and password) they probably won't be your paying customers in the future, and so, loosing "leechers" traffic might be a good thing if you want to save traffic expenses.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can handle this on the server side. Sessions are secure. Just disable in php configuration the session cookie. So the session id is added instead to the url and not stored in a cookie. So there´s no chance to manipulate something.

BUT: Handling too much files, which are already uploaded on the server causes unnecessary traffic cross the internet. So I highly recommend you to check if the user has chosen less than 10 files on client side. You are able to do this easily with javascript. Just handle the answer, which return the FileChooser Dialog (in the same way as Java does with his JFileChooser). In this answer should be the string containing all chosen files in this form:

```
"pic1.png", "pic2.jpg", "pic3.jpg"
```

So, all what you need to do is to count the occurence of file names inside this string. Simple split it about the , sign and remove the " at the beginning and the end (substring) and put your results into an array. Count the array length. If the length is greater than 10 => user has chosen too much files.

Comment: The client side limitation is already applied, but it was just that I didn't trust it on its own. So you are saying that sessions in URLs make this all safer? How exactly?

Answer (score -1):

You can limit file selection from client side

```
$('#fileupload').change(function(){
    var files = $(this)[0].files;
    if(files.length > 10){
       //do what you want , like alert warning
       // and disable submit button
    }else{
      //do what you want , like enable submit button
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zainabed/nze2B/92/)

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't fully read my question. I'm trying to avoid client side checks only and enforce those checks on the server side as well. Whatever comes from the client is not to be trusted.